# Responsive CSS Image Anchor tags - Image Maps style

Tags: css, image, anchor, responsive-design, imagemap

I've been working on a responsive site and have come to a bit of a problem with Image Maps. It seems that Image Maps don't work with Percentage based co-ordinates.
After a bit of googling I found a JS workaround - http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html.
However I want the site to work with JS disabled.

So after exhausting those possibilities I decided to look into using relatively positioned Anchor tags over the images to do the same thing. This is a better option anyway IMO.
I've tried to place the anchor tags over the image with percentage based position and size, but whenever I rescale the browser the anchor tags move disproportionately to the image.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="block">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/toys/blocks/abc_blocks.png">
  </div>
  <a href="#" class="one"></a>
  <a href="#" class="two"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#block img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.one{ 
  height:28%;
  width:19%;
  top:-36%;
  left:1%;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}
a.two{
  height:28%;
  width:19%;
  top:37%;
  left:36%;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle to describe what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/wAf3b/10/. When I resize the HTML box everything becomes skewed.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try with margin-left and margin-top instead of top and left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had a few problems with your CSS in the fiddle you posted (as well as a missing closing `div` tag).  After making sure that `#block` was relatively positioned, not 100% height, and that your anchors were block/absolutely positioned, I was able to get the tags to move with the blocks.

Here is the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wAf3b/24/

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#block{ float:left; width:100%; max-width: 400px; position: relative; }

#content{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#block img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.one{ height:28%; width:25%; position: absolute; top:55%; left:5%; display:block; background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);}
a.two{ height:28%; width:25%; position: absolute; top:60%; left:70%; display: block; background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Bulky Waste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="block">
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.wpclipart.com/toys/blocks/abc_blocks.png">
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="one"></a>
            <a href="#" class="two"></a>
        </div>
    </div><!--/content-->
</body>
</html>
```

One important thing to note with the new html is the use of `DOCTYPE`.  For some reason, some browsers don't like it when it is not capitalized.

Comment: @Jawad Thank you for the link.  I had personally thought that the DOCTYPE declaration was case insensitive as well, but had an issue about a year ago that was fixed by capitalizing it.

Comment: How times change? It was only a few years back EVERYBODY was shunning html and preferring XHTML. Now everybody is back on the wagon of HTML5 syntax.

Comment: @Jawad Agreed.  HTML5 seems to have some pretty nice features.  Looking forward to full implementation of HTML5-spec soon.

Comment: It was meant to be an ironic comment! I still close my empty elements with />, I still use lower case for tags/elements and attributes, I still close elements/tags in reverse order and I still provide the type attribute while with the MIME type of html as opposed to application+xml - Polyglot - http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-polyglot-20121025/

Comment: @Jawad I like the "This is a work in progress" warning at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Great, thanks for that @Jawad Sorry about the broken Markup - It was a quick example and didn't thoroughly check it over. Won't make that mistake again! Also, didn't know that about the Doctype. Was pretty sure that it was case sensitive. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout, so they cannot inherit relative dimensional properties from their parent. You'll need JavaScript to do what you want.

People who disable JS expect a degraded experience already.