# Responsive element positioning over image

Tags: javascript, angular, position, scale

I am writing a component which allows a user to create clickable regions over an image, these are rectangles which are then represented as an anchor in the viewer.  The editor is working correctly and the elements are correctly positioned but when the viewer loads the anchor elements are no longer correctly position.

The viewer renders the following html template

```
<div *ngIf="config.element.question.title" [froalaView]="config.element.question.title" [style.color]="config.survey.theme.colors.answerTextColor"
  class="C(#1d3a4e) Fz(16px) Fw(700) Fs(n) Td(n) Mt(0) Mx(0) Mb(3px) Pt(0) Px(0) Pb(3px) Bd(n) Pos(r) W(100%)"></div>
<div class="Pos(r) Maw(100%) H(a) Bgc(#ffffff) Pe(n)">
  <img [attr.src]="config.element.question.imageUrl" class="Pos(r) T(0) B(0) Start(0) End(0) Maw(100%) Pe(n)" />
  <div class="Pos(a) T(0) B(0) Start(0) End(0) Pe(n)">
    <a *ngFor="let map of config.element.question.imageMaps" class="imageMap Pos(a) Pe(a)" [style.top.px]="map.top" [style.left.px]="map.left"
  [style.width.px]="map.width" [style.height.px]="map.height" [attr.href]="map.link" [attr.target]="map.target">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `imageMaps` array looks like this `[ { "id": "d65843cd-5668-4578-a367-e2793f356b7e", "top": 165, "left": 162, "width": 191, "height": 71 } ]` (NOTE: `link` and `target` are optional)

I think the issue is that the image is a different size (smaller) in the editor to the viewer (larger) and larger again in the preview so as the image changes size the overlay remains in the same position.

It may be worth noting that in editor and viewer there is a panel to the left which is not there in the preview and there is some element of padding and margin in the editor.

I am not quite sure how to go about adjust the position and size of each overlay element relative to the image size and scale so if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: You would need to use percentages that mapped to your x-y coords of the anchor (and also percentage width / height) - see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500015/responsive-css-image-anchor-tags-image-maps-style

Comment: So dumb question (probably) but how do you go about converting the x/y coords to a percentage of the image?

Comment: NM, said it was a dumb question, so I figure calculating the x/y divided by the container width multiplied by 100 will give my the position as a percentage, same goes for width, then specify the anchor position and size as percentage.  I will give that a try and update my findings.